# Get the last revisions of list of files

Tags: mercurial

I got a list of files, a and b and x/y. The goal is to have the following output:

```
revision1 a
revision2 b
revision1 x/y
```

The revision before each file is the last revision that changes this file. Couldn't figure this out, is there a single command that can do this? Thanks!
The thing I want to avoid is to have 100 separate commands for 100 files, which will be so slow.

Comment: I don't think there's currently an efficient way to do this in one command.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there seems to be not a comprehensive command to get that information for all files at once.

I'd put it into a simple script though:

```
for f in $(hg manifest); do echo $(hg log $f -T"{rev}\n" | head -n1) $f; done
```

Thus I query the list of files which comprise the repository, and then query the information for each. The above gives output like

```
53 .hgignore
52 .hgtags
44 abc
43 bar
19 blah
48 dir1/f1
47 dir2/f2
```

But can be easily changed.

Comment: I stead of using `head -n1`, it would be better to use `log -l 1 ...`